# Select MAX(value),value2,value3 not returning other's value

Tags: mysql, sql

**This is my query :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(nb_played), id_person,id_list FROM `t_stats` ORDER BY MAX(nb_played) DESC;
```

i want to return the **max value of nb played for every id list**, then return the id person.

so basically, The best nb_played of every id list, with the id_person.

Can't manage to figure it out. anyone could help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t_stats t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id_list, MAX(nb_played) AS max_nb_played
    FROM t_stats
    GROUP BY id_list
) t2
    ON t1.id_list = t2.id_list AND t1.nb_played = t2.max_nb_played;
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response ! However, it's returning my table, not only the max nb_played for id_list.
i want the best of every id list, which means, for example =
id_liste : 1
max_nb_played : 3
id_personne : 1

id_liste : 2
max_nb_played : 6
id_personne : 1 (same person)

but this query return every rows of my table

Comment: @Somedude Try my edited answer.  Without seeing your data, it is easy to misinterpret as I just did.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from t_stats s
where s.nb_played = (select max(s2.nb_played)
                     from t_status s2
                     where s2.id_list = s.id_list
                    );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `t_status(id_list, nb_played)`, so the performance can be better than using `group by`.